# Get locations that lie within any given pincode of any country

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using a text field which collects addresses. When an address is selected I want to check it to see if the address is aligned with where we can deliver our products to.

How can I get a list of all addresses which lie in an area according to a given pincode?

PS: This feature is needed on a WordPress website so if there is any plugin that may help, then please tell.

Comment: What is pincode in this case?

Comment: pincode or you can say zipcode.

Comment: And what do you mean by address? Street, City, Country?

Comment: street city and country

Comment: In Europe I never heard using the word pincode, that's postcode or ZIP, that's right.

Comment: in India we use pincode i.e,zipcode